# Есть Строка разной длины, как вывести первый символ начиная с первого слова и его первого символа и дальше после каждого пробела?

Tags: javascript

function Abbr(words) {

}
Это должно быть как функция
Тоесть пользователь вводит к примеру "привет как дела" а получает "пкд" 
Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[str.split("разделитель")](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) — разбивает строку на массив, убирая из неё переданный разделитель

[arr.map(func)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) — Вызывает функцию для каждого элемента массива и подменяет этот элемент на результат вызова функции.

[arr.join("строка между элементами")](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) — собирает элементы массива обратно в строку.

```js
let str = "Привет, как дела ?"; 

console.log( ex1(str) );
console.log( ex2(str) );
console.log( ex3(str) );

/***/
function ex1(str) {
  let words = str.split(" ");
  let result = "";
  
  for( let i = 0; i < words.length; i++ ) {
    let word = words[i];
    if( /[a-zа-яё]/i.test(word[0]) ) {
      result += word[0];
    }
  }
  
  return result;
}

function ex2(str) {
  return str.split(" ").map(word => /[a-zа-яё]/i.test(word[0]) ? word[0] : "").join("");
}

function ex3(str) {
  /* Так можно, но не нужно. (см. "регулярные выражения") */
  return str.match(/(?<=^|\s)([a-zа-яё])/ig).join("");
}
```

В вариантах со `split(" ")` есть допущение: Всё что начинается с пробела, считается словом. Чтобы брать только слова, можно добавить небольшую проверку:

`/[a-zа-яё]/i.test(word[0])` — [Аниглийские или русские буквы], `i` — insensitive (т.е. и заглавные, и мелкие), проверяет на совпадение `word[0]` первую букву слова. Возвращается true или false.

`.map(word => /[a-zа-яё]/i.test(word[0]) ? word[0] : "")` (тернарный оператор): Если выражение вернет true, возьмется word[0], иначе: Пустая строка, которая не повлияет на результат после join(""). Был бы другой разделитель вместо пустой строки, пришлось бы переписать его в виде

`str.split(" ").map(word => word[0]).filter(letter => /[a-zа-яё]/i.test(letter) ).join("")`

Comment: Спасибо большое...но не понял как в проверить на совпадение с буквами

Comment: @Ярослав Добавил уточнение) Хотя, `str.split(" ").map(word => word[0]).join("")` - так оно выглядит в самом простом виде.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ запустил ваш код со split(" ")-ом и даже если пробелы перед словом выводит правильный результат....может я что-то не пойму?)

Comment: @Ярослав `alert( "Ааа Ббб 444 Ссс ?".split(" ").map(word => word[0]).join("") );` — берет еще 4 и вопросительный знак)

Answer (score 2):

```js
let words='привет как дела'

function Abbr(words) {
  words=words.split(' ') //сначала отделим слова друг от друга пробелами и получим массив в котором слова будут выглядеть вот так: ['привет','как','дела']
return words.map(i=>i[0]).join('')// после вернём нулевые нулевые индексы каждого элемента в массиве и соеденим их при помощи join('')
}
console.log(Abbr(words)) //и выводим в консоль
```